# Запрет на повторный запуск программы

Tags: c#, wpf

Можно как-то запретить запуск программы, если она уже запущена?

Comment: Если это ваша программа - проверяйте при запуске наличие Mutex или Event. Если есть - завершаете работу, если нет - создаете.

Comment: Разумеется, можно. Вот толковый ответ на SO: [What is the correct way to create a single instance application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы не можете запретить запуск нового экземпляра, но этот самый новый экземпляр может проверить наличие другого экземпляра и выйти.

Например, используя именованный Mutex.

```
class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnStartup(args);

        if (!InstanceCheck())
        {
            // нажаловаться пользователю и завершить процесс
        }
    }

    // держим в переменной, чтобы сохранить владение им до конца пробега программы
    static Mutex? InstanceCheckMutex;
    static bool InstanceCheck()
    {
        bool isNew;
        var mutex = new Mutex(true, "<your application unique name>", out isNew);
        if (isNew)
            InstanceCheckMutex = mutex;
        else
            mutex.Dispose(); // отпустить mutex сразу
        return isNew;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Не забудьте заменить текст `<your application unique name>` на какую-нибудь уникальную для вашей программы строку.

Comment: у меня метод OnStartup Visual Studio не видит  
base.OnStartup(args);

Comment: @andrew: А вы его в какой класс положили?

Comment: в класс, где создаётся главное окно

Comment: @andrew: Это класс, производный от `Application`?

Comment: нет,  у меня не находит Application

Comment: @andrew: Если у вас WPF-программа, то в ней не может не быть класса, производного от `Application`. Ищите лучше :) Ну или в крайнем случае, если не найдёте, возьмите метод `InstanceCheck()` и перенесите его куда-нибудь.

Comment: нашёл. Оказывается надо было просто добавить using System.Windows

Comment: Отсутствует частичный модификатор в объявлении типа "WpfApplication1"; существует другое частичное объявление этого типа.  
Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: @andrew: Вы наверное создали _новый_ класс? Поищите, у вас уже должен быть такой класс, в него и добавляйте.